# How to fade into specific opacity?

Tags: edit-mode, video

this is my first time using Blender and I struggle to find tutorial on how to use the video editing tool. The problem I am having is that I want two videos to overlap but I want to set the opacity of the foreground to e.g. 0.2. Ideally, I would like it to fade into opacity 0.2.

What I have done is to put the background video in channel 2 (audio in 1) and foreground video in channel 3 (no audio). I selected all channels, right-clicked, and selected "fade in and out". Now they all start at opacity 0 and move to opacity 1. I would like to cap the opacity of the fore ground to 0.2 but whenever I select the video in channel 3 and change the opacity in the right panel (compositing, blend --> Alpha Over, Opacity --> 0.2) it changes the opacity for 1 frame.

How can I select multiple timeframes in one channel to change a parameter?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

When you add a fade effect to a strip (video or audio), some keyframes are added to the opacity (or volume) property of the strip.

Open a graph editor window to manipulate them as you need.

[image]

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much! Problem solved! Alternatively, for a faster way of doing it, I randomly discovered that setting the desired opacity and then applying the fade also works if you don't need to change the fading speed.